# Batch processing by modifying existing parameters

Tags: java, object, batch-processing

My current scenario is:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public firstMethod(String pid, String mid, ClassDefinedByMe classDefinedByMe);
    public secondMethod(String pid, String mid, AnotherClassDefinedByMe anotherClassDefinedByMe);
    public thirdMethod(String pid, String mid);
}
```

I want to convert them to use multiple values in the parameters (like I want the details in batch form). In other words, the firstMethod has list of [String pid, String mid, ClassDefinedByMe classDefinedByMe] like:

```
    firstMethod([String pid1, String mid1, ClassDefinedByMe classDefinedByMe1],[String pid2, String mid2, ClassDefinedByMe classDefinedByMe2], [String pid3, String mid3, ClassDefinedByMe classDefinedByMe3]);
```

In a similar way I would like to change the other methods signature. I want to know what is the best way to do that? I currently, made a model class consisting [String pid, String mid, Object object] and using this object I created a Collection of Objects. This seems to be a way but this object is satisfying the parameter conditions of only "firstMethod". I want to come up with a design where I could also modify "secondMethod" and "thirdMethod" like I should be able to do this:

```
  public secondMethod([String pid1, String mid1, AnotherClassDefinedByMe anotherClassDefinedByMe1],[String pid2, String mid2, AnotherClassDefinedByMe anotherClassDefinedByMe2], [String pid3, String mid3, AnotherClassDefinedByMe anotherClassDefinedByMe3], [String pid4, String mid4, AnotherClassDefinedByMe anotherClassDefinedByMe4] );
  public thirdMethod([String pid1, String mid1],[String pid2, String mid2],[String pid3, String mid3]);
```

Let me know if I need to explain it in a better way!

EDIT:

I am writing code as a core Java Application.

Answer (score 0):

qsdqsfsqfsqfqsfsdfs
Spring Data JPA by default looks for an EntityManagerFactory named entityManagerFactory. Check out this part of the Javadoc of EnableJpaRepositories or Table 2.1 of the Spring Data JPA documentation.

That means that you either have to rename your emf bean to entityManagerFactory or change your Spring configuration to:

(if you are using XML)

or

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")

(if you are using Java Config)